# R reshape wide to long using strings

Tags: r, stata, reshape

I have a table A like this:

| cou | own | ind | aus_d_a | usa_f_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUS | D | A | 3268.02 | 85.087 |
| AUS | D | B | 92.1329 | 10808.3 |

and I want to reshape it to long type data as follows, table B:

| cou | own | ind | cou2 | own2 | ind2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUS | D | A | aus | d | a | 3268.02 |
| AUS | D | B | aus | d | a | 92.1329 |
| AUS | D | A | usa | f | b | 85.087 |
| AUS | D | B | usa | f | b | 10808.3 |

but I don't know how to code it using R or Stata? anyone can help me, thanks a lot

PS: the data is just a sample, actually I have thousands of columns (three dimensions: country_ownership_industry, eg aus_d_c21), 60 countries, 2 ownership, 34 industries, so I have 4080 cols.

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate. If you want a Stata answer. ask again, but focus on Stata. (It is not good psychology or good politics to ask for solutions in two or more languages at the same time.)

Answer (score 3):

Provided your `country_ownership_industry` columns are the only ones with underscores in their column names, you can do:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

pivot_longer(df, contains('_'), names_sep = '_', names_to = c('cou2', 'own2', 'ind2'))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#>   cou   own   ind   cou2  own2  ind2    value
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 AUS   D     A     aus   d     a      3268. 
#> 2 AUS   D     A     usa   f     b        85.1
#> 3 AUS   D     B     aus   d     a        92.1
#> 4 AUS   D     B     usa   f     b     10808.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, Allan, it works so well.

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of `pivot_longer` and `separate`:

```
# using your own example data
dat1 <- tibble(
  cou = c('AUS', 'AUS'), 
  own = c('D', 'D'), 
  ind = c('A', 'B'), 
  aus_d_a = c(3268.02, 92.1329), 
  usa_f_b = c(85.087, 10808.3)
)

library(tidyverse)

dat1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = aus_d_a:usa_f_b, names_to = 'cou2', values_to = 'value') %>%
  separate(cou2, c('cou2', 'own2', 'ind2'), sep = '_')
```